# Windows search dosen't find files, even in indexed location

Tags: windows-10, search, windows-search, search-indexing

I use a folder in the root directory of my C drive to store all my files in, rather than using the My Documents set of folders.

The problem is that Windows search refuses to find an files in this location, despite me adding it to the indexing list. I have tried rebuilding the index, and have waited a long time for the Windows to index my system.

Any ideas?

Comment: the windows-search is crap. I use this tool: https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/

Comment: I experienced a similar isssue, in my case the file were not found with the default "All" filter, but I can find them by clicking on `Find results in documents` icon. See [Windows 10 search does not find documents by default](http://superuser.com/questions/1112305/windows-10-search-does-not-find-documents-by-default)

Comment: Windows search is broken. Use a decent file manager instead.