# Windows 10 search does not find documents by default

Tags: windows-10, search, windows-search

When I search for my documents in Windows 10, I press <kbd>Windows</kbd> or <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and start typing. For documents not placed in my user profile the result does not show up unless I explicitly press the `Find results in documents` button.

Example: there is a file called `findMe.odp` located in the `E:\Documents\Search` directory, the directory is set to be indexed in the `Indexing Options` settings and the indexing has completed. The Cortana is not enabled on my computer and is not available in my region. I do not see this problem when searching for documents placed in the `Documents` folder of my user profile, only in other locations, even if they are indexed.

I press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type `findme`. This is what I see:

[image: No results found]

I press `Find results in documents` and the result shows up:

[image: Best match for documents]

Is there some way to set the search so that it shows me documents by default?

*Note: While this is similar to [Windows 10 Search: Search my stuff by default](https://superuser.com/questions/1100741/windows-10-search-search-my-stuff-by-default), that question was for some kind of beta or prerelease version and the descriptions in it seem to be no longer applicable.*

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 10 1607, so it has nothing to do with the version. I also asked the same question at Microsoft Community: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/instant-search-not-working-consistently/f280643a-fe68-479f-ae22-11153d9e8274 Please use the "Me too" button on the page to make Microsoft aware of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I experienced the same thing, so I played around with it a little. It turns out, that if you start typing `doc:` or `docs:` or `documents:` then the Windows Search automatically switches to File Search Mode instead of App Search Mode. Similarly, if you wanna find apps, you can start typing `app:` or `apps:`

I know it doesn't exactly solve the issue you mentioned, but it does give you at least some ease - it did for me at least...

Comment: yes thats helpful tnx, though this really should be fixed. Setting up indexed folders very precisly to then not have them included in your search results is plainly anoying